# Using Android/Desire as a bare bones GSM modem

Tags: htc-desire, data-connection

Older GSM phones could be hooked up to a PC and you could access the baseband chip through e.g. minicom or hyperterminal and give it [AT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) commands, usually through a serial/rs232 or USB connection between the phone and the PC.

A lot of software also exists to use GSM phones as e.g. SMS gateway - which basically works by getting a serial connection to the phone and communicating with AT commands. Can one do the same with a HTC Desire, or other Android phones ?

Comment: Wow, that brings back memories. I used to know a scary amount of AT commands by heart and could troubleshoot most modem connection problems by listening to them, but can't say I've ever wanted to revisit those days with a modern phone! Most standard tethering implementations install the phone as a Windows Networking device rather than a modem emulator, no idea if any third party or manufacturer does this.

Comment: You apparently can do this with the HTC Vision, at least. I found instructions [here](http://tjworld.net/wiki/Android/HTC/Vision/RadioAnalysis#TalkingtotheRadio) which are based on a Linux/Unix environment. I tried the same instructions on my EVO and it hung when I issued the `rtask C` command, so it appeared to be *trying* to do something, but not working (maybe because it's a CDMA2000 phone? Not sure). You could give that a try but I have no idea if it works on other HTC devices.

Comment: Hmm, ok that's how far I got as well(connecting USB thru virtualbox/ubuntu on a windows host) rtask C hangs it. Though it appears , after a while, as a different device but disabled, with a device guid {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}....